# Check Not Condition in two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a list of books:

```
BookNo  BookParameter  Value 
1234        1           FN
1234        2           False
1234        3           30
1234        4           YES
2222        1           FN
2222        2           True
2222        3            25
2222        4            NO
3333        1            THR
3333        2            True
3333        3            54
3333        4            YES
4444        1            FN
4444        2            TRUE
4444        3            12
4444        4            NO
```

Please note that I cannot change the database/table structure and cannot alter any data.

I want to fetch the all the records that have `BookParameter` 1 as FN but if any record having `1=FN` has `4=YES`, then I have to omit it.
So, in my above table I want to have output

```
BookNo
2222
4444
```

I've tried the following queries:

```
select bookNo 
from ...
where bookparameter = '1' and value = 'FN'
and not(bookparameter = '4' and value = 'YES')
```

and

```
select bookNo 
from ...
where bookparameter = '1' and value = 'FN'
and bookparameter != '4' and value not in ('YES')
```

But they are fetching all records having value of `bookparameter` 1 as 'FN', ignoring completely the value of `bookparameter` 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select all the books that match bookparameter=1 and value='FN', then from the matched books exclude the books that have bookparameter=4 and value='YES'

```
   select 
        bookno 
    from 
        books b
    where 
        b.bookparameter = 1 and b.value='FN' and
        not exists
        (
            select 
              1 
            from 
                books b2 
            where b.bookno = b2.bookno 
                  and b2.bookparameter=4 and b2.value='YES'
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good use case for `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT bookNo 
FROM tableName
WHERE [BookParameter] = 1 AND [Value] = 'FN' 
EXCEPT
SELECT bookNo 
FROM tableName
WHERE [BookParameter] = 4 AND [Value] = 'Yes'
```

The result will contain only those rows fetched by the first query that do not occur in the result of the second query.

I like this option because I think it is really good readable and very simple.

You could argue that use a `GROUP BY` clause with conditional aggregation might be faster.
But thanks to the hard restrictions in the `WHERE` clauses, I assume this will be insignificant in this case.

Read more about `EXCEPT` in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Sample fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hetlPdjw)

Comment: I assume that the conditional aggregation might be faster simply because it only requires one search of the data and not two, but I suppose that a relevant index  on the table (Assuming it's large enough to benefit from the index) might actually cause the `except` solution to run even faster than the conditional aggregation (which is non-sargable)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `group by`, `sum` and `iif` can help you get the expected results.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (
    [BookNo] int, 
    [BookParameter] int, 
    [Value] varchar(5)
);
    
INSERT INTO TableName ([BookNo], [BookParameter], [Value]) VALUES
(1234, 1, 'FN'),
(1234, 2, 'False'),
(1234, 3, '30'),
(1234, 4, 'YES'),
(2222, 1, 'FN'),
(2222, 2, 'True'),
(2222, 3, '25'),
(2222, 4, 'NO'),
(3333, 1, 'THR'),
(3333, 2, 'True'),
(3333, 3, '54'),
(3333, 4, 'YES'),
(4444, 1, 'FN'),
(4444, 2, 'TRUE'),
(4444, 3, '12'),
(4444, 4, 'NO');
```

The query:

```
SELECT  bookNo 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY bookNo 
HAVING SUM(IIF(bookparameter = 1 AND value = 'FN', 1, 0)) = 1 
AND SUM(IIF(bookparameter = 4 AND value = 'YES', 1, 0)) = 0;
```

Using conditional aggregation allows me to make sure there's at least one record with 'FN' value for bookparameter 1 and no records with 'YES' value for bookparameter 4 for each value of `bookNo`.

Results:

```
bookNo
2222
4444
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nb7-P5gH)

Comment: `WHERE [BookParameter] = 1 AND [Value] = 'FN' OR [BookParameter] = 4 AND [Value] = 'Yes'` might be wise in order to hit an index

Comment: <> 'yes', but that's a valid point

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.BOOKNO
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T
WHERE T.bookparameter = '1' and T.value = 'FN'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE AS X
  WHERE T.BOOKNO=X.BOOKNO AND X.bookparameter = '4' and T.value = 'YES'
)
```

Could you please try this query

Comment: A good answer provides an explanation in addition to work code

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
SELECT t1.BOOKNO FROM #books AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT BookNo FROM #books WHERE BookParameter = '4' and Value = 'YES')t2 
  ON t1.BookNo = t2.BookNo 
WHERE t1.BookParameter = '1' AND t1.Value = 'FN' and t2.BookNo IS NULL
```

Comment: A good answer provides an explanation in addition to work code